What is the meaning of "yard" in "a yard across the street"?
This context comes from the book "To Kill A Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee.
It's the part of the book in which neighbors are fighting a fire that broke out in Miss Maudie's house.
"The men of Maycomb, in all degrees of dress and undress, took furniture from Miss Maudie’s house to a yard across the street."
What is the meaning of the word "yard" in this context?
1
US: an outdoor area that is next to a house and is usually covered by grass
Children were playing out in the yard. [=(Brit) garden]
a tree in the back/front yard (Britannica dictionary)
2
: the land around a building
the prison yard [=grounds]
— see also schoolyard (Britannica dictionary)

a courtyard. (Random House Kernerman dictionary)

Does this mean that they took Miss Maudie's furniture and put it in the front yard of one of the neighbors who lives across the street from her?

A "yard" in the US can refer to a special purpose area like a "junk yard" or a "freight yard" but in a residential neighborhood "a yard across the street" refers to the plot of land at the front or on the side of a house, often covered in grass that is kept mown short.  If there were no house there it would normally be called "an empty lot".

@TimR But what you are saying is that there is a house there and we can infer that because the word yard is used. Do I understand that correctly?

From the phrase "a yard across the street" in the context of a residential neighborhood I would indeed infer that there is a house there, as would most speakers of AmE, for the reasons I gave.

yard in the cited context just means a relatively small (garden-sized) area of land where things can be put. It may or may not be enclosed / fenced in, and may or may not be obviously "attached" to some nearby building. Consider junkyard, back yard, churchyard, graveyard,...

@FumbleFingers I agree. This is how we use yard. It doesn't only mean yard attached to a house - front yard or back yard of a house.

As you say, American English uses yard in much the same way that British English uses garden. The prototypical American house is situated on a plot of land in such a way as to effectively separate the plot into a front yard and a backyard. (Why the latter is a compound word and the former isn’t is a mystery for the ages.) The front yard is the more publicly facing of the two. If the plot is wide enough, there may also be a side yard (or two).
Anyway, in using the word yard here, with no other words or phrases to modify it, Lee highly likely intended that interpretation: implying the existence—on the plot of land opposite Miss Maudie’s—of a house. If that plot is wide enough and its house is far enough down the street, then perhaps the spot where the furniture gets put could be described as being in the side yard. There’s no hard and fast boundary between side and front yards.

It can still be a "yard" even if there's no obvious nearby building to which it's associated. At some point it becomes impossible to distinuguish "a yard" from "a vacant lot" (where in principle there could be a house for which the rest of the "lot" might be called the yard, if that house existed).

Not in American English, @FumbleFingers. Lot? Yes. Field? Yes. Property? I suppose. But without any “improvements” (buildings) it would not be a yard in American English.  Lumber yards, freight yards, school yards, dock yards, etc…. All have some improvements.

For instance, in an area being developed (i .e., where houses are being built), any particular spot that will someday be described as in a yard doesn’t meet that criterion until the house is there. Before that, the spot would be described as in the lot.

"American English" is a broad category. My comment wasn't peculiar to any particular variety of English (or indeed, era). Any section of unused land close to buildings can be a yard, even if you're not used to the usage.

@FumbleFingers, I guess I don’t understand what you mean. “Any section of unused land close to buildings can be a yard” strikes me as a decree; in any event, it does not conform to the usage that I know from living all of my six and a half decades of life (so far!) in the U.S.  If there is a dialect that does use yard in the way you assert, I would be very interested to know. What is the basis for your own claim?

I mean that I don't buy the idea that any one American can tell me that all Americans agree "X never means that". For example, a lot of Americans only use "fag" as a derogatory term for a male homosexual, which is a relatively uncommon sense for Brits (most of us think a fag is a cigarette). But I would never say "fag doesn't mean homosexual in BrE", because we're not exactly talking about two separate languages here. Especially over the last couple of decades, where gobalization and the Internet have seriously blurred such distinctions as might have existed.

...a "yard" is some small area of land that's almost certainly "owned", but it's not necessarily obvious which "adjacent property" it's attached to, and it may or may not have clear-cut fences / boundaries.

...the yard across the street (not a yard..., so not the Mockingbird context) occurs an awful lot of times in print. I don't accept that in every case one should expect to be able to identify the building to which that yard is attached. Sure, you can expect that with back yard. But that's not the general case.

Come on, @FumbleFingers, I didn’t write, “all Americans agree ‘yard never means that.’” One thing I did write is, “If there is a dialect that does use yard in the way you assert, I would be very interested to know.” And to clarify, I meant dialect of American English. The Google result you link to provides a bunch of examples of the phrase “the yard across the street,” but no evidence that any of them means anything other than the sense that I described in my answer.

Your answer includes definitely implies the existence .. of a house, which I dispute.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I understand, @FumbleFingers, that you dispute it. What I still don’t understand is the basis for your belief. The evidence I have (as yet) offered is no stronger than my life-long experience as a native speaker of American English. But your evidence is…?

my evidence is my life-long experience as a native speaker of English. This is going nowhere. Let's just leave it at that.

But @FumbleFingers, To Kill a Mockingbird is a classic of American literature. There. If you’re done, I am done.

@FumbleFingers, to avoid seeming to emphatically deny the possibility of another meaning, I have reworded.

This answer is right for this context. There's nothing to be said against it. It's a typical American space near or behind or in front of a house.

@Lambie. Totally agree. This question is about American English (clearly from the context) but I think it is worth pointing out to a non-native speaker that this interpretation is only true for AmE. If you read this in a British novel it would mean something quite different. When I first read this as a teenager I would have assumed the British meaning and misunderstood the sentence.

@timchessish I just don't get why we have to go all over the English map when a context is so clearly obvious. It's a waste of time. :)

@Lambie. Fair point. I was just trying to clarify a confusion that had already occurred.
